# Java8 Stream grouping by with toMap issue

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a class named `ConfigKey`

```
public class ConfigKey {
    String code;
    String key;
    String value;
    //omit setter and getter
}
```

I want to convert `List<ConfigKey>` to `Map<String, Map<String, Object>>`, here is my method definition

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Object> convert (List<ConfigKey> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ConfigKey::getCode, 
            Collectors.toMap(ConfigKey::getKey, ConfigKey::getValue)));
}
```

however I want to do some changes, for each `ConfigKey` put another key to the map, e.g.

```
{ "code": "code1","key", "key1", "value": "value1"}
to Map
{"code1": {"key1":"value1", "prefix_key1": "value1" }
```

is there any API to do it like bellow:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Object> convert (List<ConfigKey> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ConfigKey::getCode, 
            Collectors.toMap("prefix_" + ConfigKey::getKey, ConfigKey::getValue))
            Collectors.toMap(ConfigKey::getKey, ConfigKey::getValue)));
}
```

Comment: do you consider `{"code1": {"key1":"value1", "prefix_key1": "value1" }}` as `Map<String, Map<String, Object>`? and Object here is not any custom class?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to avchive here. You can't map two different `Map<String, Object>` to one string `ConfigKey::getCode`, because maps by definition have only one value for each key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the `Collector.of()` factory method, which allows you to create your own collector:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Object> convert (List<ConfigKey> list) {
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ConfigKey::getCode, Collector.of(
        HashMap::new, (m, c) -> {
            m.put(c.getKey(), c.getValue());
            m.put("prefix_" + c.getKey(), c.getValue());
        }, (a, b) -> {
            a.putAll(b);
            return b;
        }
    )));
}
```

But honestly that seems a bit messy, and maybe a normal loop would've been better. The streams intention was to provide an api which does things in a more readable manner, but when you have to hackaround that construct, by introducing some extremely unreadable logic then it is almost always the better option to just do it the *old* way:

```
public Map<String, Map<String, Object> convert (List<ConfigKey> list) {
    Map<String, Map<String, Object>> map = new HashMap<>();
    for (ConfigKey ck : list) {
        Map<String, Object> inner = map.computeIfAbsent(ck.getCode(), k -> new HashMap<>());
        inner.put(ck.getKey(), ck.getValue());
        inner.put("prefix_" + ck.getKey(), ck.getValue());
    }
    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first add the new entries to the map and then group them:

```
private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> convert(List<ConfigKey> list) {
    new ArrayList<>(list).stream().map(configKey -> new ConfigKey(configKey.getCode(), "prefix_" + configKey.getKey(), configKey.getValue())).forEachOrdered(list::add);
    return list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ConfigKey::getCode,
            Collectors.toMap(ConfigKey::getKey, ConfigKey::getValue)));
}
```

I cloned the list (in order to prevent ConcurrentModificationException), then changed the keys to the "new" ones (with map) and added them to the original list - forEachOrdered(list::add).
Because the 'code' field was not changed, both entries will use it which results in 2 entries in the map